# Issue met in doing a simple SQL query through PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I created a database and two tables customer_full and customer_change through PhpMyAdmin. I successfully populated the two tables from two text files, the customer_full now contains 12902 rows while customer_change has 12947 rows, and each row has a CUSTOMER_ID field to identify each customer. The customer_change table has some new members that customer_full doesn't, and I want to capture them.

The task now I need to do is very common, I need to get the rows that only exist in the customer_change table but not exist in the customer_full table, so I wrote and executed the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_change 
LEFT JOIN customer_full ON customer_change.CUSTOMER_ID = customer_full.ID 
WHERE customer_full.ID IS NULL
```

It seems that after I submit the query in the PhpMyAdmin, it will always stay at "waiting for http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php" and finally turn out to be a time-out error.
However, if I run some simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM customer_change,customer_full
```

It will work and returning the result by simply joining every record from two tables. So I am wondering could any experts help me debug, could it be my query has a effciency issue or should I do more checking on the configuration of the PhpMyAdmin? Or could there be any other possible reasons my previous query failed?

Please pardon me if this is simple since I just began self-learning MySql. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_change,customer_full
```

Is a cross-join it joins every row in table customer_change against every row in customer_full. So it returns 12,902 x 12,947 = 167,042,194 rows. No idea why you'd want this.

The left join you've written looks correct:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_change 
LEFT JOIN customer_full ON customer_change.CUSTOMER_ID = customer_full.ID 
WHERE customer_full.ID IS NULL
```

**Missing index**
In order for it to run quickly, you need to put an index on `customer_change.CUSTOMER_ID` and an index on `customer_full.ID`.
Once you've done that it should run instantly.

**Corrupt tables**
There's also a possibility that your tables are corrupt; esp. if you're using MyISAM.
Try and run the step outlined in this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html
Or this link: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-repair-corrupted-mysql-tables-using-myisamchk/

Comment: Thanks for the indexing part. Actually I switched from using LEFT_JOIN to NOT IN, seems to be even faster.

Comment: @Robert: `select x from y where x not in (select ...)` is much much slower 95% of the time. It's only faster in your case because there are few mismatches between the tables so the `not in` list is small. If the `not in` list gets bigger it will rapidly get much slower than the `left join ... where x is null`